# Longest lines using priority queue

Tags: c, strings, memory-management, priority-queue

Inspired by a comment on [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/131881/c-the-large-print), I thought I'd exercise my C skills by implementing something like it using a priority queue.

The idea is to be able to invoke the program like this:

> ./longline 10 < /usr/share/dict/linux.words

And get it to print the 10 longest lines in the `linux.words` file.  I chose to implement the program using `getline()` which is a handy POSIX-2008 function that automatically allocates memory for the line it reads and can reuse the buffer it allocates.  It only reallocates when a new line is longer.  On my machine, using this function (defined in `stdio.h`) requires the `#define _GNU_SOURCE` that you see at the top of the file.

### The goals

The goal was primarily to implement something like a priority queue using an unordered array as a heap.  I write "something like" a priority queue because this has one particular feature -- it only keeps the *lowest* priority items if a new item is added when the queue is already full.

I also wanted to minimize memory allocations and reallocations.  Using it on the `linux.words` file mentioned above (which has 479828 words in it, one per line), `valgrind` reports:

> total heap usage: 108 allocs, 108 frees, 13,136 bytes allocated

which is satisfyingly parsimonious for a file that's 4953680 bytes long.

### Notes

The first entry in the array `items[0]` is generally not used; the top of the queue is located at `items[1]`.  In particular, `items[0]` is only used as a convenient scratch space within `pq_insert()`.

### Questions

I'm interested in a general review, and in particular anywhere the code could be better written or more clearly written.

I'm also not entirely happy with the creation of the `output_queue` to reverse the order of the items in the queue.  Is there a better way to do that?

#### longline.c

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct {
    int priority;
    char *data;
} item;

/*
 * Swap the contents of two items.
 */
void item_swap(item * a, item * b)
{
    // swap the two passed nodes
    int pri = a->priority;
    char *name = a->data;
    a->priority = b->priority;
    a->data = b->data;
    b->priority = pri;
    b->data = name;
}

/*
 * Item comparison functon.
 *
 * Returns true iff a is lower priority than b.
 */
bool item_less(const item * a, const item * b)
{
    return a->priority < b->priority;
}

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    size_t last_used;
    item items[1];
} priority_queue;

/*
 * Dump the contents of a priority queue.
 *
 * Primarily intended for troubleshooting.
 */
void pq_dump(const priority_queue * pqueue)
{
    if (pqueue == NULL)
        return;
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= pqueue->last_used; ++i) {
        printf("%lu: %d, %s\n", i, pqueue->items[i].priority,
               pqueue->items[i].data);
    }
}

/*
 * Create a fixed size priority queue and initialize.
 */
priority_queue *pq_create(size_t size)
{
    priority_queue *pq = malloc(sizeof(priority_queue) + sizeof(item) * (size + 1));
    if (pq) {
        pq->size = size;
        pq->last_used = 0;
    }
    return pq;
}

/*
 * Free all allocated memory for this queue.
 */
void pq_free(priority_queue * pqueue)
{
    if (pqueue) {
        for (size_t i = pqueue->last_used; i; --i) {
            free(pqueue->items[i].data);
        }
        free(pqueue);
        pqueue = NULL;
    }
}

/*
 * Readjust this priority queue's top three nodes,
 * returning false if no adjustment was needed.
 */
bool pq_adjust(priority_queue * pqueue, size_t * i)
{
    if (*i * 2 + 1 <= pqueue->last_used) {
        // handle case of two children
        size_t smallerchild =
            item_less(&pqueue->items[*i * 2],
                      &pqueue->items[*i * 2 + 1]) ? *i * 2 : *i * 2 + 1;
        if (item_less(&pqueue->items[smallerchild], &pqueue->items[*i])) {
            item_swap(&pqueue->items[smallerchild], &pqueue->items[*i]);
            *i = smallerchild;
            return true;
        }
    } else if (*i * 2 <= pqueue->last_used) {
        // handle case of only one child
        size_t smallerchild = *i * 2;
        if (item_less(&pqueue->items[smallerchild], &pqueue->items[*i])) {
            item_swap(&pqueue->items[smallerchild], &pqueue->items[*i]);
            *i = smallerchild;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/*
 * returns true iff item was added successfully.
 *
 * Note that if a new item is a LOWER priority
 * than the current head of queue, the new item
 * will be added, replacing the current head of queue.
 * This is opposite the usual convention for a priority queue,
 * but intentional behavior here.
 */
bool pq_insert(priority_queue * pqueue, int pri, char *name)
{
    if (pqueue == NULL)
        return false;
    if (pqueue->size == pqueue->last_used) {
        // handle full queue
        // only insert if current top priority is LESS THAN new node
        pqueue->items[0].priority = pri;
        if (item_less(&pqueue->items[1], &pqueue->items[0])) {
            pqueue->items[1].priority = pri;
            free(pqueue->items[1].data);
            pqueue->items[1].data = name;
            for (size_t i = 1; pq_adjust(pqueue, &i);) {
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        size_t i = ++pqueue->last_used;
        pqueue->items[i].priority = pri;
        pqueue->items[i].data = name;
        // assure heap order property holds
        while (i / 2 && item_less(&pqueue->items[i], &pqueue->items[i / 2])) {
            item_swap(&pqueue->items[i], &pqueue->items[i / 2]);
            i /= 2;             // go to parent
        }
    }
    return true;
}

/*
 * peek at the highest priority item in queue
 */
const item *pq_peek(const priority_queue * pqueue)
{
    if (pqueue == NULL || pqueue->last_used == 0)
        return NULL;
    return &pqueue->items[1];
}

/*
 * remove the top node
 */
void pq_pop(priority_queue * pqueue)
{
    if (pqueue == NULL || pqueue->last_used == 0)
        return;
    // move last node to top
    pqueue->items[1].priority = pqueue->items[pqueue->last_used].priority;
    free(pqueue->items[1].data);
    pqueue->items[1].data = pqueue->items[pqueue->last_used].data;
    --pqueue->last_used;
    for (size_t i = 1; pq_adjust(pqueue, &i);) {
    }
}

/*
 * remove top node, but return rather than freeing the data.
 */
char *pq_pop_no_delete(priority_queue * pqueue)
{
    if (pqueue == NULL || pqueue->last_used == 0)
        return NULL;
    // move last node to top
    pqueue->items[1].priority = pqueue->items[pqueue->last_used].priority;
    char *retval = pqueue->items[1].data;
    pqueue->items[1].data = pqueue->items[pqueue->last_used].data;
    --pqueue->last_used;
    for (size_t i = 1; pq_adjust(pqueue, &i);) {
    }
    return retval;
}

/*
 * Read the input stream, saving and printing the n longest lines
 * in descending size.
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf
            ("Usage: %s n\nwill show the n longest lines in the input stream\n",
             argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (n < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    priority_queue *pqueue = pq_create(n);
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin)) != -1) {
        if (pq_insert(pqueue, read, line)) {
            line = NULL;
            len = 0;
        }
    }
    free(line);
    priority_queue *output_queue = pq_create(n);
    const item *it;
    while ((it = pq_peek(pqueue)) != NULL) {
        pq_insert(output_queue, -it->priority, it->data);
        pq_pop_no_delete(pqueue);
    }
    pq_free(pqueue);
    while ((it = pq_peek(output_queue)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", it->data);
        pq_pop(output_queue);
    }
    pq_free(output_queue);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Allocation one too big

In `pq_create()`, this allocation:

> ```
> priority_queue *pq = malloc(sizeof(priority_queue) + sizeof(item) * (size + 1));
> ```

could be smaller by one item:

```
priority_queue *pq = malloc(sizeof(priority_queue) + sizeof(item) * size);
```

The `priority_queue` structure already contains space for one `item`, so you only need `size` more items.

#### Dead code

In `pq_free()`, this line doesn't do anything, and can be deleted:

> ```
>      pqueue = NULL;
> ```

The intent may have been to NULL out the pointer, but this line doesn't actually cause the pointer (in the caller) to be NULLed.  It only affects the local copy inside of `pq_free()`, which isn't going to be used again.  The compiler is probably optimizing that line out anyway, but the line may be misleading in the sense that it may suggest that the caller's copy is being NULLed when it isn't.

#### Make `pq_adjust()` do more

The current `pq_adjust()` function does one level of adjustment, and depends on the caller to call it in a loop.  But the three call sites for this function all have the same loop, which adjusts from the top of the heap to as far down as necessary.

If you modified `pq_adjust()` to always start at the top of the heap and adjust as far down as necessary (using a loop), you could avoid the three loops at the call sites.  It would also get rid of all the ugly `*i` pointer indirections.

#### Duplicated code

`pq_pop()` and `pq_pop_no_delete()` are almost identical.  You could remove the code duplication by rewriting `pq_pop()` as:

```
void pq_pop(priority_queue * pqueue)
{
    free(pq_pop_no_delete(pqueue));
}
```

#### Reversing the heap

Instead of using a second heap to reverse the original one, you could just pop each element off the heap and store the popped data at the end of the heap where you just vacated an entry.  For example:

```
    size_t last_used = pqueue->last_used;
    for (size_t i = last_used; i; --i) {
        pqueue->items[i].data = pq_pop_no_delete();
    }
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= last_used; i++) {
        printf("%s", pqueue->items[i].data);
        free(pqueue->items[i].data);
    }
```

Alternatively, you could just allocate new array to do the same thing:

```
    size_t last_used = pqueue->last_used;
    char **result = malloc(last_used * sizeof(char *));
    for (size_t i = last_used; i; --i) {
        result[i-1] = pq_pop_no_delete();
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < last_used; i++) {
        printf("%s", result[i]);
        free(result[i]);
    }
    free(result);
```

Comment: I used all of your suggestions except one and wrote a `pq_reverse` function along the lines of your in-place reversal function.  The only thing I didn't adopt was eliminating the `pqueue = NULL;` line; although you're right that it's technically not needed, I use it to assure that even if I attempt to use the queue again after calling `pq_free`, nothing bad will happen.

Comment: @Edward But `pqueue = NULL` does not actually cause the pointer in the caller to change to NULL.  It only affects the local variable inside of `pq_free()`, which means it doesn't do anything.  I made an edit to my answer to clarify this.

Comment: You're right -- thanks for the update.  I totally overlooked that.